# How to type mathematical symbols in gmail?

Tags: gmail, symbols

How can we type mathematical symbols like square-root, omega, integration, differentiation etc in gmail

Comment: https://www.intmath.com/help/send-math-email.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[TeX for Gmail](http://alexeev.org/gmailtex.html) is a plugin for Chrome and Firefox which adds (La)TeX capability to Gmail and Gmail Chat.

#### Installation

- Google Chrome: install [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gjnmclkoadjdljnfmbnnhaahilafoeji?hl=en).
- Firefox: Install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and then this [Greasemonkey userscipt](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/2260-gmailtex).

[image]

Comment: pythonlearner's question is problematic however. Questions about Gmail often get migrated automatically to Web Applications Q&A, however software recommendations questions are off topic at Web Applications Q&A, so the correct migration website for this question is [Software Recommendations Q&A](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Rahul-14BCE0064 Would other person (receipient of my mail) be able to see this mahematical thing corectly if his browser is not installed with LateX plugins ?

Comment: @pythonlearner Your formula will be converted to a <img> tag, whose src points to a google service, so the image will not be a  part of the email, but instead it is rendered and fetched when the mail will be read.

Comment: You should add that detail into the answer, Rahul.

Comment: The Greasemonkey userscript _[no longer works](http://alexeev.org/gmailtex.html)_ for Gmail.  This answer is now completely useless.